# Creating a table of contents for a blog post

Tags: laravel

So I have a blog created with Laravel, I am looking at adding a Table of Contents to each post that I can display on the page.  To be honest I am not entirely sure where to start with this or how simple/difficult it would be.

My post has a straightforward

```
{!! $post->body !!}
```

Within that is all my post content.  I would want to pick out all of the H2 elements to create the table of contents and clicking on each heading in the toc it would scroll to that section.

Bit of a novice overall with PHP/Laravel but would be grateful for some pointers as to how I would go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use some packages like this:
https://github.com/NikolayOskin/contents

or if you can create table of contents without any packages, You can use php and javascript for get H2 tags and create your own table of contents.